# How to get mouse events on all layers?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a grid with some overlayed elements (see a model in snippet). I need mouse events directed to different layers.

Left click should go to the grid cell (I must know which cell was clicked). Right click should go to overlay. How should I do that?

Currently I have managed to either get:

- [snippet] right clicks working correctly, left clicks redirected to parent of overlay (which can be different from what's directly under)
- [snippet without z-index] left clicks working correctly, right clicks only working if overlay is clicked where it overlays it's parent cell

```js
var eventDescription = $('span');

$('table').on('click', 'td', function() {
  var cell = $(this);

  var column = 1 + cell.index();
  var row = 1 + cell.closest('tr').index();
  
  eventDescription.text('Left click on cell ' + row + ', ' + column + '.');
});

$('table').on('contextmenu', 'div', function() {
  eventDescription.text('Right click on ' + this.getAttribute('id') + '.');
  return false;
});
```

```css
table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

td {
  position: relative;
  border: 1px black solid;
  height: 20px;
  width: 20px;
}

div {
  position: absolute;
  top: 2px;
  left: 2px;

  background-color: #e52e4e;
  width: 62px;
  height: 16px;
  z-index: 2;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<table>
  <tr><td><td><td><td><td>
  <tr><td><td><div id="bar1"></div></td><td><td><td>
  <tr><td><td><td><td><td>
  <tr><td><td><td><td><td>
  <tr><td><div id="bar2"></div><td><td><td><td>
</table>

<span></span>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, then one solution is to prevent "pointer-events" with the `div` (ie overlay) elements, during the mouse's "left-click" event cycle.

You can intercept the start of the click cycle via the `mousedown` event - at this point you can toggle a class of your `<div/>` (overlay) elements with `pointer-events:none` to prevents subsequent mouse/pointer-events from firing on your divs.

By doing this, you're allowing the left click events to effectivly by-pass the `<div/>` elements, which means the corresponding mouseup will respond to the `<td/>` "as if the div isn't there".

You'd then use the `mouseup` event to do two things:

1. perform the td/cell detection logic (that was previously in the regular `click` event)
2. restoring the default pointer-event behaviour of `div` elements by toggling the pointer event class again

Here's a working example:

```js
var eventDescription = $('span');

$('table').on('mousedown', 'td', function(event) {

  // When td is left clicked, toggle the 'stop-events' class
  // on all div/overlay elements. This prevents the divs from
  // firing the contextmenu/rightclick event that you want to
  // distinguish for those
  if(event.button === 0) {
    for(const node of document.body.querySelectorAll('div')) {
      node.classList.toggle('stop-events')
    }
  }
})

$('table').on('mouseup', 'td', function(event) {

  // If left mouse button released on td, perform the regular
  // cell detection logic, but also restore the default point-events
  // behaviour so that divs still respond to context click
  if(event.button === 0) {
    
    var cell = $(this);

    var column = 1 + cell.index();
    var row = 1 + cell.closest('tr').index();

    eventDescription.text('Left click on cell ' + row + ', ' + column + '.');
  
    // Restore default pointer events to allow contextmenu events
    // on divs
    for(const node of document.body.querySelectorAll('div')) {
      node.classList.toggle('stop-events')
    }
  }
})


$('table').on('contextmenu', 'div', function() {

  eventDescription.text('Right click on ' + this.getAttribute('id') + '.');
  return false;
});
```

```css
table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

td {
  position: relative;
  border: 1px black solid;
  height: 20px;
  width: 20px;
}

div {
  position: absolute;
  top: 2px;
  left: 2px;
  background-color: #e52e4e;
  width: 62px;
  height: 16px;
  z-index: 2;
}

/* Added this class */
.stop-events {
  pointer-events:none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<table>
  <tr><td><td><td><td><td>
  <tr><td><td><div id="bar1"></div></td><td><td><td>
  <tr><td><td><td><td><td>
  <tr><td><td><td><td><td>
  <tr><td><div id="bar2"></div><td><td><td><td>
</table>

<span></span>
```

Comment: I want left click to fall through to the cell that's exactly under. So ignoring wouldn't help. The problem is that the click bubbles to the parent cell not the cell that's positioned underneath.

Comment: @Džuris ok think I understand - just updated answer, does this help?

Comment: @Džuris you're welcome - 'mousedown' / 'mouseup' events are always a great escape hatch for these problems :-)